# RCassandra: Why is the table data from Cassandra not getting loaded in my data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, cassandra

[why there is No response after running RC.read.table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjkgh.png)

```
library(RCassandra)
connect.handle <- RC.connect(host="127.0.0.1", port=9042)
ChurnData <- RC.read.table(connect.handle, "churndata")
```

I always need to click stop to rerun the code.

Comment: how much data do you have in table?

Comment: 7043 rows.. @AlexOtt thanks for the reponse.

Comment: What exactly happens? Any output? Or just no data? Is `churndata `really at the default keyspace?

Comment: churndata is my table in Customer keyspace.

Comment: whenever i execute RC.describe.keyspace(connect.handle,'rcass') or 
RC.use(connect.handle,"Customer") any "RC." it goes in a runnung phase for hours. Theres no output. R is just excecuting RC.connect and moving to the next like. i always need to click stop to rerun this small code.

Comment: @TobiSH need help as soon as possible.

Comment: I never used RCassandra but if I got the manual right you need to login before you can run any operation. I would give it a try even if you don't have any credentials configured: `c <- RC.connect("cassandra-host")
RC.login(c, "foo", "bar")
RC.cluster.name(c)`

Comment: Are you able to run this query (`SELECT * FROM churndata`) from a commandline (`cqlsh`)?

Comment: Yeah I have actually loaded a csv file in table Churndata and it is printing all the values from the table after Quering `SELECT * FROM churndata`

Comment: its not even responsing after `RC.login(c,"cassandra","cassandra")`